# Hyperledger Fabric on Azure

Tags: azure, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I wanted to deployed and configured a Hyperledger network locally and also transfer it to Azure Hyperledger-Fabric for single organisation.

Answer (score 0):

this may help https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org - Hyperledger Composer has a single-org tutorial. However, to learn about Fabric itself, you should look at the Fabric network samples (easy to find on the web)